# SQL ORDER BY works with custom "comparators"?

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, sql-order-by

In order to get a random "permutation" of the contents of the table an option is:
`ORDER BY RAND()`

My question is how does this work in this context? It calls `RAND()` to be used as a "comparator"? Doesn't it matter that `RAND` does not take any arguments to compare?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `rand()` function, in MySQL, returns a random value every time it is called.

What happens when this processes is that the sort routine reads a record, calls the rand function, and implicitly adds a column with the random value to the record.  This column is hidden from view -- you never see it, but it is used for the ordering.

Logically, this is equivalent to:

```
select <columns in t>
from (select t.*, rand() as ordering
      from t
     ) t
order by ordering
```

Comment: Where is this documented about `ORDER BY`? What would another example function be?

Comment: @Cratylus . . . I can't find a specific reference to what happens with an expression in an `order by` in the MySQL documentation.  This explanation is my recollection of the ANSI standard for an expression in an `order by` clause.

Comment: So how would someone know that this is a "feature" of `ORDER BY` when one would attempt to create a random "permutation" of the elements?

Comment: The general principal is that an expression in an `order by` clause (or a `group by`) turns into an "invisible" column populated by the expression.  In MySQL `rand()` returns a different value for each row, so this works.  In other databases (such as SQL Server), `rand()` returns one value for the entire query -- and you do not get a random permutation.  The "feature" is a feature of the `rand()` function, not the `order by`.

Answer (score 2):

[**RAND()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand)

> returns a random floating-point value v in the range 0 <= v < 1.0.

You can provide it a optional `seeding value`

While execution, this is treated as a `virtual column` with `random numbers`. The `SQL engine` then uses this column to `sort` the table contents, treating it (the dynamic column) as any normal column (which has floating point values)

Comment: Where is this documented about `ORDER BY`? What would another example function be?

Comment: It is documented in the MySQL documentation **[SELECT syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html)** See: `ORDER BY {col_name | expr | position}`

Answer (score 0):

[`RAND()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand) returns random floating point number, so standard floating point number comparison is used to compare these values. It's like you have a floating point number column in your table schema and use it within `ORDER BY` statement. There is no magic here.